# How to design a method to estimate vx=speed in direction of swimming

Tags: measurements, sensors, acceleration, positions-measurement

We have a body that goes underwater (let's say a whale) with magnetometer and accelerometer data. I also have GPS, date, depth, pressure and temperature data.
I want to know if there is any simple way (Matlab code most preferably) to combine data from magnetometer and accelerometer to find a way to estimate speed of the body (whale).

I have thought of 2 ways to perform this but I don't know how to proceed:

1. Differentiate depth to determine speed of descend
2. Use acceleration and magnetic data to determine pitch, roll, yaw (I prefer this method).

Please feel free to provide a link if there is an already-existing matlab code for all of this.

Feel free to ask question so I can further explain. No gyroscope data

Comment: what axis is the accelerometer on?

Comment: Maybe this particular video can help you and in general the whole series may provide you with some knowledge around sensor fusion. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0rlvvYgmTvI

Comment: @TigerGuy I am not sure exactly. How can I check and answer your question? Sorry but I am quite new at all these.